# List of values as columns in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, initialization

I'm trying to create a data frame in which column names should come from list in python.
For eg:-
list=['6567565','67578','Speed','distance','allowance']
then
data frame:-

| 6567565 | 67578 | Speed | distance | allowance** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Initial values would be 0 for every column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass in an argument for the column names when you create the data frame object.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [[0]*5]
>>> data
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['6567565', '67578', 'Speed', 'distance', 'allowance'])
>>> df
   6567565  67578  Speed  distance  allowance
0        0      0      0         0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Creat the dataframe then `fillna`

```
out = pd.DataFrame(columns=l,index=[0]).fillna(0)
Out[484]: 
   6567565  67578  Speed  distance  allowance
0        0      0      0         0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the list of column names when making an empty dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

# empty df
df = pd.DataFrame()

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []


# col names
names=['6567565','67578','Speed','distance','allowance']

# empty df but with column names
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = names)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [6567565, 67578, Speed, distance, allowance]
Index: []


# populating first row with zeros
df.loc[len(df)] = 0

  6567565 67578 Speed distance allowance
0       0     0     0        0         0


# or just creating a dataframe with a row of zeros in one line
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((1, 5)), columns = names) # 1 row, 5 columns

   6567565  67578  Speed  distance  allowance
0      0.0    0.0    0.0       0.0        0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = ['6567565','67578','Speed','distance','allowance']

pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((1,5)), columns=cols)
```

Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQXXv.png)

`np.zeros((1,5))` is being used to create a 1x5 matrix which has zeros. Then the DataFrame constructor converts it into a df and you can pass the column names as a list.